# Regex in Java for URL filtering

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following segment of code to convert plain text hyperlink into html url hyperlink.

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?:https?|ftps?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+",
        "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>").replaceAll(
        "(www\\.)[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+", "<a href='http://$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```

But i notice there are certain url combination which will not convert to html hyperlink successfully. Can anyone advise on how to improve the codes to matches for those cases also?

[image]

Comment: Could you pleas post some example of your input?

Comment: Hi you can refer to the image link: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/20120202162926.jpg/ for my input:

Comment: E.g. like 
http://twitter.com/#!/SolidSnakeGTI
http://rs43lt13.rapidshare.com/#!download|46311|44541812469|fairy_tgail_045_sd.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a couple of times. Came up with a tricky pattern that works in all of your cases, it creates *valid* URLs, except the case with trailing `/` is not handled that elegantly. Hope someone suggests a quick fix for that.

Here is the code:

```
    String s="stackoverflow " +
            "http://naishe.blogspot.com " +
            "http://tw.com/#!/someTEXTs  " +
            "http://ts123t1.rapi.com/#!download|13321|1313|fairy_tale.mp4 " +
            "http://www.google.com/ " +
            "https://www.google.com/. " +
            "google.com " +
            "google.com, " +
            "google.com/test " +
            "123.com/test " +
            "ex-ample.com " +
            "http://ex-ample.com/test-url_chars?param1=val1&;par2=val+with%20spaces " +
            "something else";
    Pattern trimmer = Pattern.compile("(?:\\b(?:http|ftp|www\\.)\\S+\\b)|(?:\\b\\S+\\.com\\S*\\b)");
    Matcher m = trimmer.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 1;
    System.out.println(trimmer.toString());
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("|"+m.group()+"|");
    m.appendReplacement(out, "<a href=\""+m.group()+"\">URL"+ i++ +"</a>");
}
m.appendTail(out);
System.out.println(out+"!");
```

Here is the output

```
(?:\b(?:http|ftp|www\.)\S+\b)|(?:\b\S+\.com\S*\b)
|http://naishe.blogspot.com|
|http://tw.com/#!/someTEXTs|
|http://ts123t1.rapi.com/#!download|13321|1313|fairy_tale.mp4|
|http://www.google.com|
|https://www.google.com|
|google.com|
|google.com|
|google.com/test|
|123.com/test|
|ex-ample.com|
|http://ex-ample.com/test-url_chars?param1=val1&;par2=val+with%20spaces|

stackoverflow <a href="http://naishe.blogspot.com">URL1</a> 
<a href="http://tw.com/#!/someTEXTs">URL2</a>  
<a href="http://ts123t1.rapi.com/#!download|13321|1313|fairy_tale.mp4">URL3</a>
 <a href="http://www.google.com">URL4</a>/ 
<a href="https://www.google.com">URL5</a>/.
 <a href="google.com">URL6</a> <a href="google.com">URL7</a>,
 <a href="google.com/test">URL8</a> <a href="123.com/test">URL9</a>
 <a href="ex-ample.com">URL10</a>
 <a href="http://ex-ample.com/test-url_chars?param1=val1&;par2=val+with%20spaces">URL11</a> something else!
```

you see trailing `/`? :)

**A friendly suggestion to OP:** when providing with test case please choose a format that we can copy from. One can't copy from a JPEG to a text editor.

Comment: How can i modify the regular expression to only work with http and https hyperlinks?

Comment: try this `"\\b(?:http|https):\\/{2}\\S+\\b"`

Answer (score 0):

[URLEncoder.encode(String url, String encoding)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) should help you, no?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that should match any URLs:

```
String input = "http://rs43lt13.rapidshare.com/#!download|46311|44541812469|fairy_tgail_045_sd.mp4";
String re_url="((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s\"]*))";

Pattern url_pattern = Pattern.compile(re_url,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matches = url_pattern.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.print("Found URL!" + m.group(1));
}
```

Don't forget to import java.util.regex.* beforehand.